# Why UI not displaying properly?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am making an android cv app but I want to implement the UI shown in the  screenshot.
[screenshot of ui I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQRv9.jpg)
below current UI from real device 
[current ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCvyX.jpg)

The XML layout where I have implemented my UI, which consists of an ImageView and some TextViews which shows subjects. I have implemented all the tasks but UI is not showing how I want it to show.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorBlust"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/educationImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/education_information"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/education_info"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/education_information"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:text="@string/text_duration"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/institution"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:text="@string/text_institution"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/degree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:text="@string/text_degree"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <Space
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/subjectImage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/university_subjects"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subjects"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:text="@string/university_subjects"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <include
                layout="@layout/subject_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/subjects"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have created another adapter and created dummy data in subjectivity
below adapter class

```
      public  class SubjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private  SubjectActivity subjectActivity;
    private int [] subjectImage;
    String[] subjectText;
    List<FakeData> fakeData;



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView subjects;
        public ImageView subjectImage;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            subjectImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.subjectImage);
            subjects = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subjects);


        }
    }

    public SubjectAdapter(SubjectActivity subjectActivity, int []subjectImage, String [] subjectText, List<FakeData> fakeData){
        this.subjectActivity = subjectActivity;
        this.subjectImage = subjectImage;
        this.subjectText = subjectText;
        this.fakeData = fakeData;

    }
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.subject_list, parent, false);

            return new ViewHolder(itemView);
        }

       @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            FakeData fake = fakeData.get(position);
            Picasso.get().load(fake.getImage()).
                    into(holder.subjectImage);
            holder.subjects.setText(fake.getSubjects());
        }


        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub





    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fakeData.size() ;
    }
}
```

below subject XML where I have hosted RecyclerView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

below subject_list.xml where I have host items

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlust"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/computer_science"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/computers_science"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I have created fake data in order to host other images and texts

below fakeModel class
public class FakeData {

```
public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public String getSubjects() {
    return subjects;
}

public void setSubjects(String subjects) {
    this.subjects = subjects;
}

String image;
String subjects;
```

}

below adapter class where I have extended with RecyclerView
public  class SubjectAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private  SubjectActivity subjectActivity;
private int [] subjectImage;
String[] subjectText;
List<FakeData> fakeData;



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView subjects;
    public ImageView subjectImage;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        subjectImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.subjectImage);
        subjects = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.subjects);


    }
}

public SubjectAdapter(SubjectActivity subjectActivity, int []subjectImage, String [] subjectText, List<FakeData> fakeData){
    this.subjectActivity = subjectActivity;
    this.subjectImage = subjectImage;
    this.subjectText = subjectText;
    this.fakeData = fakeData;

}
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.subject_list, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

   @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        FakeData fake = fakeData.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(fake.getImage()).
                into(holder.subjectImage);
        holder.subjects.setText(fake.getSubjects());
    }


    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub





@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fakeData.size() ;
}
```

}

below My Subject class where I have implemented fake images and data

public class SubjectActivity extends Activity {

```
List<FakeData> fakeData;
int [] subjectImage = {R.drawable.computer_science,
        R.drawable.data_structure,

       };



ListView list;
String[] subjectText = {
        "Computer Science",
        "Data Structure",

};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subject);


    RecyclerView  recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    SubjectAdapter adapter = new SubjectAdapter(SubjectActivity.this, subjectImage,
            subjectText, fakeData);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

Comment: Please add images instead of linking to them.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you only have used Android Studio's drag and drop feature to position the UI elements. The problem is, Android Studio shows those UI elements in a generic device, which wont match all devices. When I was starting off with Android, this document helped me a lot to understand how elements in the UI must be placed.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor

Answer (score 0):

You XML is malformed. Your LinearLayout orientation is wrong:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

It should be **vertical**.

Then validate its content. You have multiple **RelativeLayout** with orientation attribute.

It should be **LinearLayout** instead. RelativeLayouts don’t have orientation.

Besides those errors, your layout is very complex and have a deep hierarchy. This will lead to performance issues. My suggestion to you is to learn how to use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout).

The learning curve is a bit high, but it will be worth it!

Comment: Sousa, I have updated code you check where I am making mistake

Comment: The same tips o gave you still apply. Also, don’t use a ListView it is deprecated. Use a RecyclerView instead.

Comment: Sousa, can you give me a sample

Comment: Google has a code lab for it. Check it at: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Fio2018#0

Comment: Andre Sousa,  How can I create fake data and showing inside recyclerview

Comment: I dont need constrainlayout

Comment: It was just a performance and modern UI development tip. You can use any view group you want ;)

Comment: can you check my dummy data code I have to finish this code today